# Total number of read/writes in a day in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Aside from using standard `count` queries with a date, is there a global way to get the number of writes (or reads for that matter) in a 24hr period on a table, or an entire schema?

Comment: Is your database all InnoDB ???

Comment: Have you looked at the performance schema?

Comment: Are you looking for _disk_ reads/writes?  _logical_ reads/writes (including cached)?  _rows_ read/written?  _SQL statements_ that read/write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE : This is all reads and writes for all databases in the MySQL Instance**

You should create a temp database for collecting stats

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mystats;
CREATE DATABASE mystats;
```

Then, every hour run this

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
USE mystats
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rwstats;
CREATE TABLE rwstats
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    stat_name  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    stat_value BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (stat_name,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
#
# Collect Stats
#
INSERT INTO rwstats (stat_name,stat_value)
SELECT variable_name,0 - variable_value
FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name IN
('Innodb_rows_inserted','Innodb_rows_updated','Innodb_rows_deleted',
'Innodb_rows_read','Innodb_data_reads','Innodb_data_read',
'Innodb_data_writes','Innodb_data_written');
#
# Sleep For 1 Hour
#
DO SLEEP(3600);
#
# Collect Stats
#
INSERT INTO rwstats (stat_name,stat_value)
SELECT variable_name,variable_value
FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name IN
('Innodb_rows_inserted','Innodb_rows_updated','Innodb_rows_deleted',
'Innodb_rows_read','Innodb_data_reads','Innodb_data_read',
'Innodb_data_writes','Innodb_data_written');
#
# Display Results
#
SELECT stat_name,SUM(stat_value) stat_value FROM rwstats GROUP BY stat_name;
```

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary logging enabled, you can analyse your binlogs to identify types and number of statements executed.

```
mysqlbinlog your_binlog | grep -i -e "^update" -e "^insert" -e "^delete" -e "^replace" -e "^alter" | cut -c1-100 | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sed -e "s/\t/ /g;s/\`//g;s/(.*$//;s/ set .*$//;s/ as .*$//" | sed -e "s/ where .*$//" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

You might need --base64-output=DECODE_ROWS for row based binlog format.
You can analyze your day worth of binlogs or use --start/--end options to select time.

Check out [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/20/identifying-useful-information-mysql-row-based-binary-logs/) and [this](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.in/2010/01/whats-in-your-binlog.html) blog posts.